# Java criação de Cadastro

Tags: java, herança, polimorfismo

Estou criando um sistema acadêmico em Java, porem estou com um problema.

Tenho 4 classes (`Principal`, `Pessoa`, `Aluno` e `Professor`).
Acredito que seja alguma coisa simples, o erro que aparece é na classe `Principal`

```
error: cannot find symbol - symbol: variable aluno - location: class Principal
```

Acredito que tenha que ligar as classes, porém não sei como fazer isso.

Classe `Pessoa`:

```
package Sistema2;

public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private char genero;

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade, char genero) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa{" + "nome=" + nome + ", idade=" + idade + ", genero=" + genero + "}';
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
```

Classe `Aluno`:

```
package Sistema2;

public class Aluno extends Pessoa {

    private String ra;

    public Aluno(String nome, int idade, char genero) {
        super(nome, idade, genero);
    }

    public String getRa() {
        return ra;
    }

    public void setRa(String ra) {
        this.ra = ra;
    }
```

Classe `Principal`:

```
package Sistema2;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Principal {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Aluno> listaDeAlunos = new ArrayList<>();

        int op = 0;

        do{
            System.out.println("##ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO##\n");
            System.out.println("1 - Cadastrar Aluno");
            System.out.println("2 - Cadastrar Professor");
            System.out.println("3 - Sair \n");
            System.out.println("Digite uma opção: ");
            op = scan.nextInt();

            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Bem vindo ao sistema de cadastro de Alunos\n");

                    System.out.println("Nome: ");
                    aluno.setNome(scan.nextLine()); //Ocorre erro

                    System.out.println("Idade: ");
                    aluno.setIdade(scan.nextInt()); //Ocorre erro

                    System.out.println("Gênero ('F' para Feminino e 'M' para Masculino): ");
                    aluno.setGenero(scan.next().charAt(0)); //Ocorre erro
                    scan.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("RA: ");
                    aluno.setRa(scan.nextLine()); //Ocorre erro

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Bem vindao ao sistema de cadastro de Professores");

                case 3:
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Opção inválida, tente novamente.");
            }
        }while(op != 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sua classe principal:

```
package Sistema2;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Principal {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Aluno> listaDeAlunos = new ArrayList<>();

        int op = 0;

        do{
            System.out.println("##ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO##\n");
            System.out.println("1 - Cadastrar Aluno");
            System.out.println("2 - Cadastrar Professor");
            System.out.println("3 - Sair \n");
            System.out.println("Digite uma opção: ");
            op = scan.nextInt();

            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Bem vindo ao sistema de cadastro de Alunos\n");

                    System.out.println("Nome: ");
                    aluno.setNome(scan.nextLine()); //Ocorre erro

                    System.out.println("Idade: ");
                    aluno.setIdade(scan.nextInt()); //Ocorre erro

                    System.out.println("Gênero ('F' para Feminino e 'M' para Masculino): ");
                    aluno.setGenero(scan.next().charAt(0)); //Ocorre erro
                    scan.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("RA: ");
                    aluno.setRa(scan.nextLine()); //Ocorre erro

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Bem vindao ao sistema de cadastro de Professores");

                case 3:
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Opção inválida, tente novamente.");
            }
        }while(op != 3);
    }
}
```

Você poderia apontar em qual linha da classe `Principal` você declarou a variável `aluno`? Pois é, eu também não! E o compilador concorda comigo.

Você não declarou a variável `aluno` em lugar nenhum e por isso que o compilador reclama.

Há pelo menos três possíveis soluções. Escolha uma.

## Solução 1

Mude o construtor de `Pessoa` para:

```
public Pessoa() {
}
```

Mude o construtor de `Aluno` para:

```
public Aluno() {
}
```

Acrescente isso logo após a linha do `case 1:`

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
```

## Solução 2

Altere o conteúdo do seu `case 1:` para isso:

```
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Bem vindo ao sistema de cadastro de Alunos\n");

                System.out.println("Nome: ");
                String nome = scan.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Idade: ");
                int idade = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Gênero ('F' para Feminino e 'M' para Masculino): ");
                char genero = scan.next().charAt(0);
                scan.nextLine();

                System.out.println("RA: ");
                Aluno aluno = new Aluno(nome, idade, genero);
                aluno.setRa(scan.nextLine());
```

## Solução 3

Parecido com a solução 2, mas você troca o construtor de `Aluno` para isso:

```
public Aluno(String nome, int idade, char genero, String ra) {
    super(nome, idade, genero);
    this.ra = ra;
}
```

E o final do `case 1:` fica assim:

```
                System.out.println("RA: ");
                String ra = scan.nextLine();
                Aluno aluno = new Aluno(nome, idade, genero, ra);
```

Comment: Utilizei a solução 3.. funcionou.. porem ao colocar executar aparece apenas o nome e idade e depois erro

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Sistema2.Principal.main(Principal.java:30)
C:\Users\474797\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 8 segundos)

Comment: @Tejota Isso acontece quando você digita para a idade algo que não é um número. Pode ser também um problema irritante que já vi algumas vezes em que o `nextLine` trás uma linha de texto e armazena uma linha em branco para ser lida em seguida.